# USB devices not working after step 7

Tags: java, android, sdk, usb

I'm was following the instructions to root the kindle fire for my friend and made it to step 7 on the instructions found at http://www.techhive.com/article/244303/how_to_root_your_kindle_fire.html

I'm not sure when my USB devices stopped working but it does not recognize them if they are unplugged and plugged back in. Of course that means that now my keyboard and mouse are no longer working, and I think it may have affected my monitor and Wi-Fi as well... :(

What do I do to fix my computer?

Answer (score 0):

If a device is unplugged from your computer while it is installing a driver, the driver installation will simply cancel, so it is highly unlikely that the problem had anything to do with rooting your kindle at all.

This is silly to ask, since you probably have, but did you try restarting your computer?

If that doesn't fix it, then there was something wrong with your computer to start with, since rooting the kindle is not something that could have caused all your USB ports to stop working.

I'm going to assume that you didn't install a virus, and if you're insistent on believing that rooting your Kindle Fire was the cause of all your USB ports failing, then you should just use System Restore back to any date before you started rooting it. (Or just reformat your computer entirely.)

Comment: I have tried restarting my computer... I'm not certain that it was the rooting that damaged my computer, but I don't believe it was a virus either. I know how to system restore, but not in the condition my computer is in right now (without any devices working...) what do I need to do to fix this problem?

Comment: If your mouse and keyboard don't work, you have no way of resetting/system-restoring your computer.

But if you do manage to get it to work, here's how you can system restore your computer :

Turn off your computer. Turn it on, then immediately start mashing F8 until a black screen shows up with a bunch of options. 

From there, if you are on either Windows 7 or Windows 8, there should be an option called Troubleshoot, where you can then system restore/reset your computer.

Optionally, you can also system restore by booting it into safe-mode, and system restoring it from there.